# Django NoReverseMatch at /create/

Tags: python, django

I want to create a system. For this system I need to a patient create form. When I click the button, I can save the patient but there is a error page after I pushed it.

> Reverse for 'create' with keyword arguments '{'slug': 'James'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['create/$']

(When I fill the form, I write James into **title**  field) And even I write James, in mySql database, title column is like id. 1, 2, 3, ... etc not James...

Where is my mistake? Thanks a lot.

**urls.py**

```
app_name = "patients"

urlpatterns = [

re_path('patients/', views.PatientList.as_view(), name='patients_list'),

url(r'^create/$', patient_create, name='patient_create'),

path('create/<slug:slug>/', views.PatientsDetail.as_view(), name='patients_detail'),
]
```

**models.py**

```
class newPatients(models.Model):

title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
dept = models.TextField()
address = models.TextField()
phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
notes = RichTextField(verbose_name="notes")
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True, editable=False)

def publish(self):
    self.published_date = timezone.now()
    self.save()

def __str__(self):
    return self.first_name

def get_create_url(self):
    return reverse('patients:patient_create', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

def get_unique_slug(self):
    slug = slugify(self.title.replace('ı', 'i'))
    unique_slug = slug
    counter = 1
    while newPatients.objects.filter(slug=unique_slug).exists():
        unique_slug = '{}-{}'.format(slug, counter)
        counter += 1
    return unique_slug

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('patients:patient_create', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.slug = self.get_unique_slug()
    return super(newPatients, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class Meta:
    ordering = ['-created_date']
```

**traceback**

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/create/

Django Version: 2.2.9
Python Version: 3.7.0
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'users',
 'patients',
 'widget_tweaks',
 'crispy_forms',
 'ckeditor']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\edeni\senior\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\edeni\senior\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\edeni\senior\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\edeni\senior\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  21.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\edeni\senior\pharsys\patients\views.py" in patient_create
  31.             return redirect(newPatients)

File "C:\Users\edeni\senior\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py" in redirect
  58.     return redirect_class(resolve_url(to, *args, **kwargs))

File "C:\Users\edeni\senior\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py" in resolve_url
  134.         return to.get_absolute_url()

File "C:\Users\edeni\senior\pharsys\patients\models.py" in get_absolute_url
  40.         return reverse('patients:create', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

File "C:\Users\edeni\senior\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py" in reverse
  90.     return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))

File "C:\Users\edeni\senior\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  673.         raise NoReverseMatch(msg)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /create/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'create' with keyword arguments '{'slug': 'james'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['create/$']
```

Comment: Don't mix `url` and `path`. Use `re_path` if you want to use regex. But also the name of your url pattern is 'patient_detail' not 'create' (in `get_absolute_url`).

Comment: @dirkgroten I fixed and edited my question, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the error (check for lines in your **own** code):

```
File "C:\Users\edeni\senior\pharsys\patients\views.py" in patient_create
  31.             return redirect(newPatients)

...

File "C:\Users\edeni\senior\pharsys\patients\models.py" in get_absolute_url
  40.         return reverse('patients:create', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

It tells you the error is in your `get_absolute_url` method (which gets called from your redirect). And it tells you it can't reverse 'create' with keyword arguments '{'slug': 'james'}'. Well, that's clear now, your url pattern `create` doesn't have an argument 'slug'. Probably you didn't mean "create" (would be strange for a detail view) but "patients_detail"?

Comment: Now I edit my code and question but still same error shown

Comment: That's not possible. The error shows you the exact code that it's running so if you still see `40.         return reverse('patients:create', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})` it means that your new code isn't running. Did you restart your server?

Comment: Now I restart sever and it works.Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

One of the culprits of NoReverse Match

```
{ 'name' }
```

or

```
{ 'app:name' }
```

one or the other will work

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [answer]. It isn't very clear how to apply this answer to the problem in the question.